# Flex mobile application TextInput width issue

Tags: apache-flex, mobile, width, textinput

I made a simple Flex mobile application to test TextInput fields. I define my View with width=height=100% and use vertical layout. Inside I'm simply placing static TextInput components with width of 100, 200, 300, 400 respectively.
I'm also displaying the width of each TextInput in its text property and it shows values which I've defined. What bothers me is the actual width of the TextFields doesn't match the properties of the phone emulator I'm running (Samsung Epic WxH = 480x775) or actual device. For instance the TextInput with width of 400 completely extends past the left and right sides of the device, while it should be contained inside it: it's 400 pixels wide and device has 480 usable pixels available. So do all other TextInputs. They look lot wider they they should be. What the issue here? Am I missing something trivial? Thanks.

Comment: When going to setup a mobile app I noticed the option to automatically scale for different DPIs, by default it appears to be un-checked but perhaps this is causing your problem, in their Learn More link it brings you to here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa8161994b114d624-33657d5912b7ab2d73b-7fe2.html#WSe4e4b720da9dedb53d70042612e27c5c3d4-7ffc I'm still going to just try to replicate what your seeing out of curiousity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That did in fact make all the difference.  When creating the application if you check the box to auto-scale for other DPIs it sets this property on the ViewNavigatorApplication

applicationDPI="160"

If I don't check the box that property isn't added and I get the behavior you were expecting if that property is included and/or I did check the box then it is adjusting the pixel values assuming that I wrote it for a 160 DPI screen and it now needs to scale the value for a 320 DPI screen.

Comment: I also ran this guy on my phone just for the heck of it, got a Galaxy Nexus, 500 is about 3/4 of the screen running the one where I didn't set the 160 DPI application size, I see the 500 box stretch beyond the screen width (which wouldn't make sense except it's scaling that up to 1000px due to the difference in screen density).

Comment: It's really amazing how easy it is to create a simple mobile application and test it out.  If I just weren't so darn lazy when it comes to my own work I probably would have built something awesome by now... perhaps a better stack-overflow app :), though I don't think you can create widgets this way... of course James Ward covered that :) http://www.jamesward.com/2011/05/11/extending-air-for-android/ <- Always Informative/Amazing

Comment: Hi Shaun,
thanks for a quick reply. So, basically what you saying is this.
if applicationDPI is set to a some value, ex: 160. Flex will scale every component based on it's run time DPI using ratio
runtimeDPI/applicaitonDPI? For instance if I set applicationDPI=160 and create a control with width=100. At runtime, on a device with 240 DPI, flex will scale my control width to be 100*240/160=150 device pixels? I guess this makes sense if we want a control to have the same physical dimensions on various device DPIs.

Comment: But then we shouldn't rely anymore on expressing properties like width/height in pixels when coding for mobile.Does it mean, we should avoid completely pixel based measurements while laying out controls when using applicationDPI and use percents and top/bottom/left/right constraints as the only options? Sorry if this wasn't clear to me from the flex docs.

Comment: It really depends on the application and the layout.  In some cases this scaling it does for you automatically can be beneficial, if it's causing you problems you can simply not specify an application DPI but then nothing with explicit sizes set will change based on the screen.  Since there is such a wide variety in the screens displaying Android apps I'd think you generally want to go constraint based but really lots of testing is the only real way to figure out what the best solution is for a given problem.  Sorry I know that's not a clear answer either, but it depends.